# Невозможно перенести виджеты из "Widget Box" в редактируемое окно в Qt Designer

Tags: pyqt5, qt-designer

Хочу сделать окно в Qt Designer для программирования на питоне. Но столкнулся с непонятной проблемой: я не могу перенести виджеты (из панели где все они представлены) в окно для компоновки, они как будто заблокированы. Если нажать на любой из них левой кнопкой и отпустить, то ничего не происходит. Пробовал версию Qt Designer 5.11.1 и 5.14.1 - все то же самое. QtDesigner запускается изнутри QtCreator'а (версия 4.12.2). ОС: Windows 10. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?

Пример файла ui (это файл по-умолчанию, так как я не могу его редактировать графическими средствами):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>test</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="test">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>test</string>
  </property>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: опубликуйте пожалуйста ваш файл `.ui`

Comment: Да, было дело. Установите QtCreator и запускайте из-под него https://www.qt.io/download-open-source?hsCtaTracking=9f6a2170-a938-42df-a8e2-a9f0b1d6cdce%7C6cb0de4f-9bb5-4778-ab02-bfb62735f3e5

Comment: @AlexanderChernin QtDesigner запускался также из-под QtCreator(4.12.2). Панель с виджетами не реагирует ни в одном случае. Хоть из QtCreator запускать, хоть просто установить через pip.

Comment: @S.Nick опубликовал пример файла. Но это то, что по-умолчанию генерируется.

Comment: Сносите все и переустанавливайте

Comment: @AlexanderChernin ясно. Видимо какая-то слишком специфическая проблема, раз нужно ОС переустанавливать.

Comment: Не ос, а питон и qt под него